# SqlConnection in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlconnection

In VB.NET I can use:

```
Protected Conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Active").ConnectionString)
```

However, when I do the following in C#:

```
protected SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn"));
```

I get the error:

> The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

Then if I change it to:

```
protected SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn"));
```

I get the error:

> Non-invocable member
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' cannot
>   be used like a method.

Why is this and how can I connect to my SQL Server database using C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this:

```
protected SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString
);
```

Notice the `[]` instead of `()` which is what is used to access an element of an array in C#. Also notice the usage of the `.ConnectionString` property call as the `SqlConnection` constructor expects a string.

Comment: I'm still getting `The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context`. But I've added `System.Configuration` to my References

Comment: @Curt - try adding "using System.Configuration;" at the top. And remember to also use the using statement as Ofer Zelig suggests.

Comment: @Curt, make sure you have referenced the `System.Configuration` assembly to your project and that you have added a `using System.Configuration` in order to bring the `ConfigurationManager` class insto scope.

Comment: I definetely have referenced it and I've used `using System.Configuration` too... very confused

Answer (score 8):

Change the last pair of parentheses to square brackets.
In C#, parentheses are used in method calls, whether square brackets are used to access members inside a collection (or so).

In addition, use the `using` clause to ensure that the connection is always closed and disposed when you go out of scope:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"]))
{
...
}
```

Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you *read* collections using square bracket syntax:

e.g.

```
string[] strings = new[] { "first", "second", "third" };

string secondString = strings[1];
```

So you access the Configuration collection like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"];
```